# Putting a text in the header in all Excel's sheets (loops: foreach, for) - low performance (C#)

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-interop

I'd like to insert the text into the header of EACH sheet in Excel. Unfortunately, it takes a very long time. I tried two loops: foreach and for. Below is a simple code I'm using with a stopwatch. It looks like Excel needs about 0.7 sec for one sheet. Even with ONE sheet in the loop, it takes 0.5 sec. and the more sheets are open the longer it loops for everyone. Of course, the case with one sheet is just to picture the situation. For 10 sheets it takes 7,5 secs and I need to do it every time the user saves the workbook. With the auto-save option enabled, it can be challenging.

I believe there is another possibility to do it, but I can't find any solution. I read about marshalling, but 7,5 secs? Perhaps there is something such as fast build-in multiple insertions like let's say AllSheets.PageSetup.LeftHeader?

Can you share your experience on this topic?

```
//aWb is an Active WorkBook

Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

foreach (Excel.Worksheet ew in aWb.Worksheets) //7:541 for 10 sheets
{
    ew.PageSetup.LeftHeader = "LeftHeader";
}
sw.Stop();
MessageBox.Show("Foreach: " + sw.Elapsed.Seconds + ":" + sw.Elapsed.Milliseconds);

sw.Reset();
sw.Start();

for (int x = 1; x <= Application.Sheets.Count; x++) //7:318 for 10 sheets
{
    aWb.Sheets[x].PageSetup.LeftHeader = "LeftHeader";
}
sw.Stop();
MessageBox.Show("For: " + sw.Elapsed.Seconds + ":" + sw.Elapsed.Milliseconds);
```

Comment: Which fraemwork/nuget pack do you use?

Comment: How about Parallel.ForEach??

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. I added the following code:

 Parallel.For(1, Application.Sheets.Count, x =>
 {
  oWb.Sheets[x].PageSetup.LeftHeader = "LeftHeader";
 });

There is slight progress, but still far from the acceptable threshold. 
Results (two tries):

(8:310; 7:630; 6:895)
(7:593; 8:400; 6:910)

Comment: VSTO doesn't work well with multithreading, you are likely to run into COMExceptions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd recommend turning off the following properties to improve the overall performance:

- [Application.ScreenUpdating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.screenupdating?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm133205)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv15)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396) - Turn screen updating off to speed up your macro code. You won't be able to see what the macro is doing, but it will run faster. Remember to set the ScreenUpdating property back to True when your macro ends.
- [Worksheet.EnableCalculation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.enablecalculation?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm175079)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv15)%26rd%3Dtrue) - True if Microsoft Excel automatically recalculates the worksheet when necessary. False if Excel doesn't recalculate the sheet. When the value of this property is False, you cannot request a recalculation. When you change the value from False to True, Excel recalculates the worksheet.
- [Application.Calculation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.calculation) - Returns or sets an XlCalculation value that represents the calculation mode.

Also, I'd suggest playing with the [Open XML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk), sometimes it is much faster to get the job done without Excel automation.